# Как сделать скрипт по ведению логов на сервере дискорд

Tags: python, логирование, discord

У меня есть сервер дискорд и я хочу чтобы при запуске скрипта Python он записывал все сообщения со временем в отдельный текстовый документ. Есть [документация](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/logging.html) от дискорда, но это не то что мне нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

пример:

```
def log(message):
    print(datetime.now())
    print("Сообщение от {0} {1} (id = {2}) \n {3}".format(message.from_user.first_name,
                                                              message.from_user.last_name,
                                                              str(message.from_user.id), message.text))
```

Comment: А какая библиотека?

Comment: это просто пример логирования, как видите функция принимает объект содержащий всё что имеется в сообщении и выводит в удобном виде